# What is the "js-datepicker" class in filterrific gem on a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, filterrific

I tried to add the gem 'filterrific' in my Ruby on Rails application and i don't find how to add a datepicker like the demo : http://filterrific-demo.herokuapp.com/students

I suppose there is an other gem or js framework / library to add the datepicker, i can see a class:'js-datepicker' in the input but i don't find the js code.

Nothing in the wiki or in the readme.

Here is the view :

```
<%# app/views/students/index.html.erb %>
<h1>Students</h1>

<%#
  Filterrific adds the `form_for_filterrific` view helper:
  * adds dom id 'filterrific_filter'
  * applies javascript behaviors:
      * AJAX form submission on change
      * AJAX spinner while AJAX request is being processed
  * sets form_for options like :url, :method and input name prefix
%>
<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
  <div>
    Search
    <%# give the search field the 'filterrific-periodically-observed' class for live updates %>
    <%= f.text_field(
      :search_query,
      class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed'
    ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Country
    <%= f.select(
      :with_country_id,
      @filterrific.select_options[:with_country_id],
      { include_blank: '- Any -' }
    ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Registered after
    <%= f.text_field(:with_created_at_gte, class: 'js-datepicker') %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sorted by
    <%= f.select(:sorted_by, @filterrific.select_options[:sorted_by]) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to(
      'Reset filters',
      reset_filterrific_url,
    ) %>
  </div>
  <%# add an automated spinner to your form when the list is refreshed %>
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<%= render(
  partial: 'students/list',
  locals: { students: @students }
) %>
```

the controller :

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # Initialize filterrific with the following params:
    # * `Student` is the ActiveRecord based model class.
    # * `params[:filterrific]` are any params submitted via web request.
    #   If they are blank, filterrific will try params persisted in the session
    #   next. If those are blank, too, filterrific will use the model's default
    #   filter settings.
    # * Options:
    #     * select_options: You can store any options for `<select>` inputs in
    #       the filterrific form here. In this example, the `#options_for_...`
    #       methods return arrays that can be passed as options to `f.select`
    #       These methods are defined in the model.
    #     * persistence_id: optional, defaults to "<controller>#<action>" string
    #       to isolate session persistence of multiple filterrific instances.
    #       Override this to share session persisted filter params between
    #       multiple filterrific instances. Set to `false` to disable session
    #       persistence.
    #     * default_filter_params: optional, to override model defaults
    #     * available_filters: optional, to further restrict which filters are
    #       in this filterrific instance.
    #     * sanitize_params: optional, defaults to `true`. If true, all filterrific
    #       params will be sanitized to prevent reflected XSS attacks.
    # This method also persists the params in the session and handles resetting
    # the filterrific params.
    # In order for reset_filterrific to work, it's important that you add the
    # `or return` bit after the call to `initialize_filterrific`. Otherwise the
    # redirect will not work.
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Student,
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {
        sorted_by: Student.options_for_sorted_by,
        with_country_id: Country.options_for_select,
      },
      persistence_id: "shared_key",
      default_filter_params: {},
      available_filters: [:sorted_by, :with_country_id],
      sanitize_params: true,
    ) || return
    # Get an ActiveRecord::Relation for all students that match the filter settings.
    # You can paginate with will_paginate or kaminari.
    # NOTE: filterrific_find returns an ActiveRecord Relation that can be
    # chained with other scopes to further narrow down the scope of the list,
    # e.g., to apply permissions or to hard coded exclude certain types of records.
    @students = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])

    # Respond to html for initial page load and to js for AJAX filter updates.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  # Recover from invalid param sets, e.g., when a filter refers to the
  # database id of a record that doesn’t exist any more.
  # In this case we reset filterrific and discard all filter params.
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    # There is an issue with the persisted param_set. Reset it.
    puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{e.message}"
    redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) && return
  end

  ...

end
```

the model :

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  # db columns:
  # integer: id
  # string: first_name
  # string: last_name
  # text: email
  # integer: country_id
  # datetime: created_at

  # This directive enables Filterrific for the Student class.
  # We define a default sorting by most recent sign up, and then
  # we make a number of filters available through Filterrific.
  filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: "created_at_desc" },
    available_filters: [
      :sorted_by,
      :search_query,
      :with_country_id,
      :with_created_at_gte,
    ],
  )

  # ActiveRecord association declarations
  belongs_to :country

  # Scope definitions. We implement all Filterrific filters through ActiveRecord
  # scopes. In this example we omit the implementation of the scopes for brevity.
  # Please see 'Scope patterns' for scope implementation details.
  scope :search_query, ->(query) {
    # Filters students whose name or email matches the query
    ...
  }
  scope :sorted_by, ->(sort_key) {
    # Sorts students by sort_key
    ...
  }
 scope :with_country_id, ->(country_ids) {
  where(country_id: [*country_ids])
}
  scope :with_created_at_gte, ->(ref_date) {
    ...
  }

  # This method provides select options for the `sorted_by` filter select input.
  # It is called in the controller as part of `initialize_filterrific`.
  def self.options_for_sorted_by
    [
      ["Name (a-z)", "name_asc"],
      ["Registration date (newest first)", "created_at_desc"],
      ["Registration date (oldest first)", "created_at_asc"],
      ["Country (a-z)", "country_name_asc"],
    ]
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you add model and controller files to question also?

Comment: I just add the model and the controller, but i just want to know the js library/framework used with the gem